# Should I use the standalone Keras library or tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

As Keras becomes an API for TensorFlow, there are lots of old versions of Keras code, such as https://github.com/keiserlab/keras-neural-graph-fingerprint/blob/master/examples.py

```
from keras import models
```

With the current version of TensorFlow, do we need to change every Keras code as?

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
```

Comment: According to [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras), they adhere to the Keras API specification, so there seems to be no need to change code. Just make sure the versions are aligned, i.e. `pip install keras==<tf.keras.__version__>`. Though that might require code updates, if the code in question uses deprecated API specifications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Keras and tf.keras in TensorFlow 1.1+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068899/what-is-the-difference-between-keras-and-tf-keras-in-tensorflow-1-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing things up:

- Keras (https://keras.io/) is a library independent from TensorFlow, which specifies a high-level API for building and training neural networks and is capable of using one of multiple backends (among which, TensorFlow) for low-level tensor computation.
- `tf.keras` (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) implements the Keras API specification within TensorFlow. In addition, the `tf.keras` API is optimized to work well with other TensorFlow modules: you can pass a `tf.data` Dataset to the `.fit()` method of a `tf.keras` model, for instance, or convert a `tf.keras` model to a TensorFlow estimator with `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`. Currently, the `tf.keras` API is the high-level API to look for when building models within TensorFlow, and the integration with other TensorFlow features will continue in the future.

So to answer your question: **no, you don't need to convert Keras code to tf.keras code**. Keras code uses the Keras library, potentially even runs on top of a different backend than TensorFlow, and will continue to work just fine in the future. Even more, it's important to not just mix up Keras and `tf.keras` objects within the same script, since this might produce incompatabilities, as you can see for example [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53821855/why-keras-does-not-allow-to-add-a-convolutional-layer-in-this-way/53821915#53821915).

**Update**: Keras will be abandoned in favor of tf.keras: https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174019423541157888